# Java Importing org-jdesktop-layout in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, import, layout-manager, jdesktop

I have added the org-jdesktop-layout.jar to my libraries in my netbeans in my project. I found this .jar file in: `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.0.1\platform\modules`

However the following line of code is still not recognized:

```
org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
```

I think I am missing the right import statement. What is the right import statement? If there is any other information that would be useful, let me know! Also what determines the prefix for an import statement?

**EDIT**: The following code seems to be from an older GUI library. I have two options, convert to newer GUI standards or access old GUI standards? I have never done anything like this before. What can I do?

```
org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING)
                    .add(jButton1)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(jLabel1)
                            .add(jLabel2))
                        .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(capFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .add(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.RELATED)
                                .add(wtFormattedTextField, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 69, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))))
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
```

I think this might be an older library...
Thanks in advance

Comment: For 1.6+, swap it out for [`javax.swing.GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/GroupLayout.html).

Comment: What about the object LayoutStyle?

Comment: For posterity, replace `.add` by `.addGroup` / `.addComponent`, etc. And use `.addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)` for `LayoutStyle.RELATED`, `layout.createParallelGroup(GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)` for `GroupLayout.TRAILING`.
Or `GroupLayout.HORIZONTAL` by `SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL`.

Answer (score 7):

You have to import the library class you want,

```
import org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout;
```

but you also have to right-click on the project's `Libaries` node, choose `Add Library…` and select `Swing Layout Extensions`. It should already be there waiting.