# NetBeans jFrames not working (just showing loading...)

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, netbeans-7, netbeans-platform

I created a new project in Netbeans IDE 7.0.1.  In that project I created a new `JFrame` form.  But that frame is not loading.

Then I tried to run the program anyway and it gave the following exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  Uncompilable source code - package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
at login.initComponents(login.java:33)
at login.<init>(login.java:20)
at login$1.run(login.java:78)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Clean and build and try again

Comment: I thought `Uncompilable source code - package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist` is pretty clear.  And you should not try to run these things before they compile cleanly.

Comment: Would you please show us the code you tried to execute

Comment: From where can I add that package??

Comment: Show us the code you are trying to execute..

Comment: Often just [**Googling the error given**](https://www.google.com/search?q=package%20org.jdesktop.layout%20does%20not%20exist) will find you your anwers, as you're probably not the first person to ask on the web, this problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Importing org-jdesktop-layout in Netbeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094566/java-importing-org-jdesktop-layout-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to add the **Swing Layout Extensions Library** to your project, to do so go to the Projects explorer, do right-click on *Libraries* > *Add Library...* and select **Swing Layout Extensions Library**. Problem solved.

BTW this is a Duplicate from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304700/netbeans-jframes-do-not-work

Answer (score -1):

Example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello world");

            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setSize(600,500);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: @AndrewThompson where in the question does it say that it has to import it. The answer has been given to add clarity to the user who asked a question on how to run JFrame. Additionally the example above is for reference.

Comment: *"where in the question does it say that it has to import it."*  Read the 2nd line of the output.  It was the **first line** until I manually inserted a line break.  See also my comment which was made a minute before yours..

Comment: I Followed your example ,and its working when I am running the codes..But the jframe is not loading in the design.. E.Doroskevic

Comment: and frame.setVisible(true); should be last code line, after sizing is done

Comment: In NetBeans and under your project in question under your projects tab, right click on the folder named Libraries. Click on "Add Library" and then scroll to find "Swing Layout Extensions". Select "Swing Layout Extensions" and then click the "Add Library" button. The error should have gone away. @user3192893