# Can't load Jframe in "Design" view

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I've done some simple project(calculator with GUI, I'm in learning phase :D ) in NetBeans,
it all worked well, compiled and everything worked fine. So,day after, I decide to move on to something new, but when i opened NB, GUI(from the Calculator project) didn't show up(in the "Design" view) it just said "Loading..."

[image: screenshot of "loading..."]

I ignored this and tried to create a new project, but that didnt work out, after setting up and pressing "Finish" button it just did... well nothing :/
"Finish" button just faded and I was stuck with this (check ss below)

[image: Screenshot of new project]

I've tried cleaning cache from `/home/[myUsername]/.netbeans/7.0/cache` (this suggestion I've found while Googling the solution of my problem) which didn't work.

After that I decided to go to StackOverflow and before asking new question I searched for my problem and actually found someone with same problem ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21160203/netbeans-jframes-not-working-just-showing-loading)) but he didnt get much of a solution, neither did he give much of details :/

So I've decided to try the suggestions from comments first:

- Clean and build and try again
- Looks like you have to add the Swing Layout Extensions Library to your project

It didn't work, but my problem was a bit different, I had my project already built successfully so i can still run it, even though it won't show up in Design view, i just couldn't do any change to Calculator project(would get same error as he did) nor could i make a new one.

Now I would like to know is this a bug in NetBeans or am I doing something wrong and how to fix it if it's possible?

---

Im using Linux Mint 16, NB version 7.0.1(latest)
Calculator project:
////[GUI.java code](http://pastebin.com/YB0ivxtk/)

---

*Im sorry for using links instead of other types of formatting, but i think like this its kinder to eye due to code being too long.


Thanks for your effort and time, and sorry if its a problem due to my stupidity*

Comment: The latest version of Netbeans is 8.0.2 (I think), you'll need to check the logs to determine what's going on, it's possible that Netbeans encounter an error while trying to load the form, try performing a clean and build first

Comment: @MadProgrammer 8.0.2 is indeed latest version, but for Windows. On Linux it's 7.0.1, at least that's what NetBeans says. I tried Clean&Build already, it builds successfully, because there are no problems with project itself(that's what I think) but the Design view won't show my work :/
The problem doesn't appear when I try to run the project, but when I open the NetBeans itself. 
I also can't make new project(now I've checked, it creates the folder but not the project itself and wont show up in NetBeans) 
Btw thanks for edit guys :)

Comment: Try deleteing the cache and checking the logs

Comment: @MadProgrammer Ok, there is some progress :D
-Clean&build - not helping |||
-Cleaning cache - not helping |||
-cleaning cache+restarting PC - works good, but after I turned off then turned on NetBeans it's back to old problem, cleaning cache+restart is not helping anymore :/
-Log shows something about Form Designer module that can't be loaded, I can send it if you want..

Comment: If `GUI.form` is missing, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19715788/230513).

Comment: @trashgod it looks like it's problem with IDE itself, i checked log and googled the part of it that was marked as 'SEVERE' where it mentioned something about Form Designer thing not being able to load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to MadProgrammer I've found a solution, looks like it's a 'known bug' in this version of NetBeans, which is apparently obsolete(even tho the program itself says it's the latest)
Upgrading to 7.1.2 should fix the problem, will update if it works...

**UPDATE**
Works like a charm :)
Bug was fixed in 7.1.2 currently new is 8.0.2. `apt-get` gives me 7.0.1 as latest :/

P.S. Had problems with NetBeans from official site too, it won't accept the jdk path, so i suggest downloading it from oracle [JDK+NB bundle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7-netbeans-download-432126.html)

---

I've got this version through `sudo apt-get install netbeans` , I'll try downloading from their site