# How to solve error: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I have an assignment to make a Java application with a GUI in NetBeans. I made the GUI in the editor, and when I tried to compile it, I get bunch of these errors

```
error: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
```

So I looked up on the internet what to do if these errors come up, and I found out to `import org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout;`, but it did nothing, it just gave me a bonus error:

```
error: package org.jdesktop.layout does not exist
import org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout;
```

If anyone knows what this is, or how I can fix it, I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094566/java-importing-org-jdesktop-layout-in-netbeans/14103287

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the SO question identified by @KrystianG, so check the answer to that question for how to resolve the import. However, since that answer is fairly old that specific approach might not be valid now. If so, update your question accordingly.